# datadir not exist while installing mysql using puppet

Tags: mysql, puppet

I am trying to install mysql using puppet, but I am getting this error :

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Service/Service[mysqld]: Dependency Mysql_datadir[/data] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Service/Service[mysqld]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Service/Exec[wait_for_mysql_socket_to_open]: Dependency Mysql_datadir[/data] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Service/Exec[wait_for_mysql_socket_to_open]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/Exec[remove install pass]: Dependency Mysql_datadir[/data] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/Exec[remove install pass]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/Mysql_user[root@localhost]: Dependency Mysql_datadir[/data] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/Mysql_user[root@localhost]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/File[/root/.my.cnf]: Dependency Mysql_datadir[/data] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server::Root_password/File[/root/.my.cnf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/Anchor[mysql::server::end]: Dependency Mysql_datadir[/data] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Mysql::Server/Anchor[mysql::server::end]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Info: Stage[main]: Unscheduling all events on Stage[main]
Error: Could not find a suitable provider for mysql_datadir
```

I have created the datadir manually /data, but still it is showing datadir not exist.

puppet hierafile :

```
mysql::server::config_file: '/etc/mysql/my.cnf'
mysql::server::create_root_user: true
mysql::server::restart: true
mysql::server::service_name: 'mysql'
mysql::server::root_password: 'root'
mysql::server::service_provider: systemd
mysql::server::override_options:
  mysqld:
    bind-address: '127.0.0.1'
    datadir: '/data'
    expire_logs_days: 10
    key_buffer_size: '16M'
    log-error: '/var/log/mysql/error.log'
    max_allowed_packet: '16M'
    max_binlog_size: '100M'
    max_connections: 151
    pid-file: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid'
    port: 3306
    socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
    ssl: 'false'
    ssl-ca: '/etc/mysql/cacert.pem'
    ssl-cert: '/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem'
    ssl-key: '/etc/mysql/server-key.pem'
    tmpdir: '/tmp'
    user: 'mysql'
  mysqld_safe:
    log-error: '/var/log/mysql/error.log'
    nice: 0
    socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
  mysqldump:
    +!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

puppet manifest:

```
node example {
  include mysql::server
  include mysql::client
}
```

Since the datadir exists, it is still showing the datadir dependency failure error.

Comment: The error messages implies your operating system does not support file operations.

Comment: so how to solve this problem? any suggestions @MattSchuchard ??

Comment: What is the operating system you're trying to install this on and is it supported? There is a list of supported OS's here https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/mysql